# jQuery animation on a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have following HTML:

```
<div class="olympics" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 250px; top: px;">

   <a style="display: inline-block; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 5px;" href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a style="display: inline-block; float: left;  height: 20px; margin: 5px;" href="#">Link 2</a>

 </div>​
```

and JS:

```
$('.olympics a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
        color: "#fff"
    }, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#aa0000"
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Any idea why this animation does not work? 
jsfiddle demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/NzhxH/13/**

Comment: The inevitable next question is how to stop the queue of animations (hovering over them multiple times causes a seizure-fest).  Use `.stop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/NzhxH/29/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you include the jQueryUI package in your import?  After I added it in your fiddle it's working

http://jsfiddle.net/NzhxH/19/

Comment: Haha your answer was 3 seconds faster than mine :)
+1

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use jquery ui and have a lighter website

u can do this with 2 ways

css3:

http://jsfiddle.net/NzhxH/41/

```
-webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
```

jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/NzhxH/39/

```
$('.olympics div').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('span').stop().animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 1000);
    $(this).children('a').delay(800).css({'color':'#fff'});
}, function() {
    $(this).children('span').stop().animate({
        opacity:0
    }, 1000);
    $(this).children('a').delay(800).css({'color':'#aa0000'});
});​
```